# Conditional Reading in react working but shouldn't?

Tags: reactjs, components, conditional-statements, rendering

So the question is, this code works perfectly but why when I remove the return(Header /) it doesn't work but it returns the correct Header type when return(Header /) is there depending on what the props.weather is?

Surely it should return  and not any others if its depending on it?

also if anyone can re-format this any better feel free, relatively new to it.

```
import Header from './header'
import HeaderCloudy from './headercloudy'
import HeaderSunny from './headerSunny'
import HeaderRaining from './headerRain'

function HeaderLoadOut(props){
//log weather from api by city
console.log(props.weather);
//convert
  let types = {
    weather: props.weather
  }
//check weather load weather

if (types.weather == 'Clouds'){
  return <HeaderCloudy />
} else if (types.weather == 'Sunny'){
  return <HeaderSunny />
} else if (types.weather == 'Clear'){
  return <HeaderSunny />
} else if (types.weather == 'Rain'){
  return <HeaderRaining />
} else if (types.weather == 'Snow'){
  return <HeaderRaining />
}

console.log(types.weather)
return (
  <Header />
)

}
export default HeaderLoadOut;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an object to map your `weather` type, also, in functional component you must [render a react element](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), therefore you must supply a node like `Header` or [any value as specified in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored).

```
const WEATHER_TYPE = {
  Clouds: <HeaderCloudy />,
  Sunny: <HeaderSunny />,
  Clear: <HeaderSunny />,
  Rain: <HeaderRaining />,
  Snow: <HeaderRaining />
};

function HeaderLoadOut({ weather }) {
  return weather ? WEATHER_TYPE[weather] : <Header />;
}

export default HeaderLoadOut;
```

As stated in docs, `undefined` is also a valid react element:

```
function HeaderLoadOut({ weather }) {
  return WEATHER_TYPE[weather];
}
```

Comment: That's Awesome thanks, never would have thought of doing it like that, my next step was a switch statement.